# Turn PS3 Slim into Linux server

Tags: firmware, ps3

I have a PS3 Slim that I wish to turn into a Linux server but I don't know how to go about doing this. My specific ps3 has a model number of CECH-2101A. Where do I need to go to get the modded firmware and do I need to take the hard drive out to install Linux onto it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an [extensive guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=343113) based on Ubuntu 6.10 from 2007 but you probably will fail to install it on your PS3.

The "other OS" option was disabled by firmware 3.21 in April 2010 and you will at least need an unpatched PS3 with a lower version.

And then you got another problem: all the how to's will be about Ubuntu released older than 2010 and would require very good knowledge about the inner working of a PS3, the differences of old Ubuntu and new Ubuntu and how that impacts the old how-to's to use on a newer release.

> Where do I need to go to get the modded firmware

There is no firmware for it and you also can not downgrade the firmware on the PS3 slim below the firmware it originally came with. That in itself makes me believe you will not be able to. A PS3 slim probably had firmware 3.40 and also will not even have a "other OS" option in the firmware.

> and do I need to take the hard drive out to install Linux onto it?

No, the hard disc is there to install games and does not contain the PS3 software itself. The system software is stored in the Synergistic Processing Element. It has 8 of these: 1 for the system software, 6 for developers and the last one for a backup in case one of the other 7 fail.

Comment: The PS3 firmware is stored in a flash chip on the motherboard, not on the SPE itself. (Just like a PC BIOS is stored in a flash chip, not in the CPU or northbridge.)